# Android animation leaving empty space at the bottom

Tags: android

I am able to animate two views up at the same time like this

```
int height = mSwitcher.getHeight();
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSwitcher, "translationY", 0, -1 * height).setDuration(1000).start();
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mBottomView, "translationY", 0, -1 * height).setDuration(1000).start();
```

The problem is there is an empty space below where the last view moved up. I am trying to find a way for the last view mBottomView to grow and take up this space.

Comment: Did you manage to get the solution? I too am facing a similar problem.